# ASP.NET Single Page Application (SPA)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js, marionette, asp.net-spa

I am new to ASP.NET Single Page Application (SPA) using Backbone.js and Marionette.js

Can anybody provide a solid code example with explanation to get started with Visual Studio 2012

**Actually, I need a working example in VS2012 using ASP.NET SPA(MVC4) + Backbone.js and Marionette.js instead Knockout.js**

here is one which I liked the most so far:
http://blog.patrickmriley.net/2013/06/mvc4-marionette-todomvc-template.html?showComment=1375253174438#c3265360992803109932

but still no code explanation.

**Any help will be highly appreciated.**

Thanks

Comment: His example is here https://github.com/priley86/marionette-mvc4-bootstrap-template. Which kind of code explanation do you need?

Comment: I needed step by step guide if possible, I already downloaded his sample.

Comment: could you please start doing your first steps and ask for help in particular points but not in common. This is a tutorial question and is not wanted on SO.

Comment: I've started creating a Backbone and Marionette application using Service Stack.  I have an update to push soon and I am hoping to put documentation and videos online discussing the internals of the application.  This example uses marionette's layout feature so there are many working parts. https://github.com/kalpers/BackboneApplication  I am also looking for developers who want to participate.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/saqibshakil/SPA-Sample-App

this is my project on GitHub, it does not use MVC4 instead it uses WCF JSON service. But the service is detachable. Implemented using marionette and and a host of other open source library.

Support IE8 onwards. IE7 support just needs the inclusion of JSON2 library